# Transparent x86 emulation using QEMU on Raspbian

Tags: raspbian, qemu, cups, x86, emulation

I'm trying to setup transparent x86 emulation on Raspbian according to this tutorial: https://wiki.debian.org/QemuUserEmulation. The issue is that after enabling multiarch and running `sudo apt-get install libc6:i386`, the package is missing (it's not available in the repository). Where can I get that package? Is it even possible to get it running on Raspbian, or should I switch to other Linux distro for Raspberry?

Similar issues:

- [Running X86 binaries on armv7](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/215864/running-x86-binaries-on-armv7)
- [Using x86 CUPS filter on Raspbian](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/164646/using-x86-cups-filter-on-raspbian)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use the multiarch approach for transparent emulation using QEMU, you need to find a distribution which supports all the architectures you’re interested in (your native architecture, and directly-supported alternate architecture you want, and the architectures you want to emulate). You can’t mix and match distributions (*e.g.* Raspbian for `armhf` and Debian for `i386`) because multiarch requires that packages installed for multiple architectures be installed with *exactly* the same version on all architectures.

Switching to another distribution would make this easier (assuming the distribution itself is a nice match for your Raspberry), but there may be another solution — it should be possible to use `debootstrap` to install another distribution with a foreign architecture in a chroot on your Raspberry, and use that to run binaries... I’ve used transparent emulation with multiarch, and foreign architectures with `debootstrap`, so I know the various components work, but I’ve never tried combining them so that’s left as an exercise for the reader.